# Expo eject throwing error - Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies, check your npm logfile or run npm install again manually

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, eas

Till few hours ago expo eject was working completely fine. Suddenly it has started throwing error.

**Things to consider:**

1. I recently updated to Node v16 and npm v8.
2. Tried uninstall expo-cli, re-installing, downgrading, upgrading.
3. To install packages I have to run npm with flag --legacy-peer-deps. But, most likely it's because I have npm above v8 and few packages uses v6 or below (Found this online).

**Versions:**

- Node - 16.16.0
- npm - 8.14.0
- expo - 5.4.12

[Link to the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9nS2.png)

**P.S.** - I am new to posting questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dependencies are not getting located. Try running `yarn install` this might solve the problem.

Comment: The issue seemed to be npm version. Expo uses an older version while I upgraded to a newer one causing the issue. Once I downgraded it started working.